# How to Deploy Signal -Private Messenger and Voice calling application in my own server

Tags: message

I would like to deploy the application **Signal** developed by *Open Whisper Systems* in my own server. Currently I own a private cloud linux VM with internet access and Debian 8 installed. Some one please give me a steps to achieve my goal. This is all for my learning and personal use. After I succeed in it I can make a detailed tutorial doc for everyone who like to make their own. So some one kindly give me details.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? I need to do something similar.

Comment: Hi Warren , I didn't got any help on deploying signal however I managed to put on another application which works pretty similar. You can use the open source free service provided by them or you can try installing in your own server. Its a part of guardian project and the service provider is OSTEL (https://ostel.co/). You can find the installation wiki over here (https://dev.guardianproject.info/projects/ostel/wiki/Server_Documentation ). However , I did installed it quite a different way since I was using Mysql instead of PostgreSQL. Drop an email if you 'er stuck and I 'll help you as I can

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look!